# embed roots of unity from valued field into its residue field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity, valuation-theory, local-field

Let $K_v$ non-archim valued complete local field with finite
residue field $\kappa= \mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{m}_v$ of characteristic $p$.
Assume $K_v$ contains $d$th roots of unity $U_d$.

Is there sufficient numerical condition to decide when
these roots of unity are canonically contained in the
residue field $\kappa$?

The point is that even though because
$\kappa^{\times} \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^f}^* $ for appropriate $f$ contains every cyclic group $C_d$ with $d \vert  (p^f -1)$ by Lagrange, this not tells if the restricted residue map $\text{res}:\mathcal{O}_k^* \to \kappa^{\times}$ with kernel $1+ \mathfrak{m}_v$ embeds $U_d$ injectively into $\kappa$ making $U_d$ naturally $dth$ roots of unity in $\kappa$.

Is there any characterization when the res map restricted
to $U_d$ is injective and therefore embeds the roots of
unity into residue field, equivalently when
$U_d \cap (1+ \mathfrak{m}_v)=\{1\}$?

Comment: … always, as long as $d$ is coprime to $p$?

Comment: @Aphelli: I agree a posteriori :) Essentially by *uniqueness* of Hensel lifts as KCd explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going backwards: use Hensel's lemma to uniquely lift each nonzero element in $\kappa$ to a root of unity in $\mathcal O_K^\times$ that preserves its order.

There are no $p$-power roots of unity in a finite field, other than $1$, so the order of any root of unity in a finite field is not divisible by $p$. And they *all* lift to roots of unity in $\mathcal O_K^\times$.

**Theorem**.  *When $K$ is a local field with a residue field of size $q$, the polynomial $x^q - x$ splits completely in $\mathcal O_K[x]$ and its roots are distinct when reduces to the residue field.*

*Proof*. Let $f(x) = x^q - x$ and $a \in \mathcal O_K$. Since all elements in $\kappa$ equal their own $q$th power and $q = 0$ in $\kappa$, we have $f(a) \equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak m_K$ and $f'(a) = qa^{q-1} - 1 \equiv -1 \not\equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak m_K$, where $\mathfrak m_K$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_K$. So by Hensel's lemma there is a *unique* root $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ in $\mathcal O_K$ such that $\alpha \equiv a \bmod \mathfrak m_K$.   As $a$ runs over a set of representatives in $\mathcal O_K$ for $\kappa$, we obtain $q$ roots of $f(x)$ in $\mathcal O_K$ that are incongruent mod $\mathfrak m_K$, and $\deg f = q$, so we have obtained all the roots of $f(x)$.  QED

**Theorem**.  *When $K$ is a local field with a residue field of characteristic $p$ and $m$ is a positive integer not divisible by $p$, two $m$th roots of unity in $\mathcal O_K$ that are equal in $\kappa$ must be equal in $\mathcal O_K$.*

*Proof*.  Let $z^m = 1$ in $\mathcal O_K$ and $f(x) = x^m - 1$, so $z \not\equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak m_K$. Since $f(z) \equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak m_K$ and $f'(z) = mz^{m-1} \not\equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak m_K$, by Hensel's lemma there is a *unique* root $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ in $\mathfrak O_K$ such that $\alpha \equiv z \bmod \mathfrak m_K$.  Since $z$ is such a root, $\alpha$ must be $z$: the only $m$th root of unity in $\mathcal O_K$ that's congruent to $z \bmod \mathfrak m_K$ is $z$.  QED

If you understand the proofs of these two theorems, use similar ideas to show that when $\overline{a} \in \kappa^\times$ has order $d$ (so $d \mid (q-1)$), the unique $\omega$ in $\mathcal O_K$ that's a root of $x^q-x$ and satisfies $\overline{\omega} = \overline{a}$ in $\kappa$ must have order $d$.

Roots of unity in $K$ are in $\mathcal O_K^\times$, each nonzero coset in the residue field contains a unique $(q-1)$th root of unity by the first theorem above, and $p \nmid (q-1)$ (as $q$ is a power of $p$), so by the second theorem above the *only* roots of unity in $K$ with order relatively prime to $p$ are the $(q-1)$th roots of unity: $x^{q-1} - 1$ splits completely in $K[x]$ and its roots exhaust the prime-to-$p$ order roots of unity in $K$.

**Example**.  When $p$ is prime, the prime-to-$p$ roots of unity in $\mathbf Q_p$ are the roots of $x^{p-1} - 1$, which has one root in each nonzero coset of the residue field, which has order $p$.

I have not said anything about nontrivial $p$-power roots of unity in a local field with residue field characteristic $p$. They could only occur in a characteristic $0$ local field (a finite extension of $\mathbf Q_p$) and they don't admit as straightforward a description as the prime-to-$p$ roots of unity, except they will all be in $1 + \mathfrak m_K$ since in the residue field the only $p$-power root of unity in a finite field with characteristic $p$. The $p$-power roots of unity in $\mathbf Q_p$ require turn out to be $\pm 1$ when $p = 2$ (note $-1 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$) and $\{1\}$ when $p > 2$.

Look up the Teichmuller lifting for more information about prime-to-$p$ roots of unity in local fields of characteristic $0$ with residue field characteristic $p$.

Comment: nice, so from this we can conclude the the now! trivial consequence that of $K$ contains $m$th roots of unity with $m$ not divisible by $p$, characteristic of residue field $\kappa$ of $K$, then $m$ gives a lower bound for $ \vert \kappa \vert$

Comment: Sure. The largest value of  $m$, when it is not divisible by $p$, is $|\kappa| - 1$.

Comment: What about the other extreme? Is it possible to construct a local field with finite residue field of fixed size say $p^f$, $p$ it's characteristic, which contains $(p \cdot m)$th roots of unity for arbitrary big $m$? Moreover, do we know some structural result about the restriction of the res map $\text{res}:\mathcal{O}_k^* \to \kappa^{\times}$ to $U_{p \cdot m}$, eg what is in the kernel; does it's image exactly consist of $m'$th roots where $m=p^s \cdot m'$ and $p$ not divides $m'$?

Comment: I can't tell how much work you have put into these questions yourself already.  Work out the residue field of the cyclotomic extension $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_{n})$, where $n = p^sm'$ and $p \nmid m'$.

Comment: Thank you, the case $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n)$ is very illuminating
as it captures exactly all features which could more or 
less happen with roots of unity in local fields. 
The fields of type $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^m}))$ contain 
obviously roots of unity of arbitrary big degree, but the
residue field stays $\mathbb{F}_p$, so this answers one part of
the question in the last comment.

Comment: moreover since the group of $n$th roots of unity is a cyclic group
$\cong C_n$ and a cyclic group contains exactly one (also cyclic) 
subgroup $C_d$ for every $d$ dividing $n$, the analysis about 
what happens with roots of unity of a local field in it's residue
field, could be splitted up in separate analysis of two key cases:
(1) $n$ coprime to $p$ and (2) $n=p^m$ as we can write $n$ as $n'p^s$
and analyse the unique subgroups satisfying (1) or (2) 
separately.